# Crypto algorithm list

Tags: javascript, algorithm, node.js, cryptography, hmac

I'm trying to find a list of `strings` that can be used a a crypto algorithm to fit into this function, replacing `SHA256`.

```
crypto.createHmac("SHA256", secret).update(string).digest('base64'),
```

I've come to the understanding that crypto uses `openssl`, and that the algorithms are specific to each system running node.js.

With the following commands you can see a list of all algorithms available for your system.

```
openssl list-cipher-algorithms 
openssl list-cipher-commands
```

I've outputted the content of those two commands to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/4459803).

**What bothers me is that `SHA256` is not in either of those lists.**

I would really like the definitive algorithm list.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The learning here is that `ciphers` and `hashes` are different and use different algorithms. With node's `crypto` use `.getCiphers()` and `.getHashes()` methods to return an array with the names of the supported `ciphers` and `hashes` respectively.

```
var crypto = require('crypto')
console.log(crypto.getCiphers())
console.log(crypto.getHashes())
```

Which logs the following ciphers:

```
[ 'CAST-cbc',
  'aes-128-cbc',
  'aes-128-cbc-hmac-sha1',
  'aes-128-cfb',
  'aes-128-cfb1',
  'aes-128-cfb8',
  'aes-128-ctr',
  'aes-128-ecb',
  'aes-128-gcm',
  'aes-128-ofb',
  'aes-128-xts',
  'aes-192-cbc',
  'aes-192-cfb',
  'aes-192-cfb1',
  'aes-192-cfb8',
  'aes-192-ctr',
  'aes-192-ecb',
  'aes-192-gcm',
  'aes-192-ofb',
  'aes-256-cbc',
  'aes-256-cbc-hmac-sha1',
  'aes-256-cfb',
  'aes-256-cfb1',
  'aes-256-cfb8',
  'aes-256-ctr',
  'aes-256-ecb',
  'aes-256-gcm',
  'aes-256-ofb',
  'aes-256-xts',
  'aes128',
  'aes192',
  'aes256',
  'bf',
  'bf-cbc',
  'bf-cfb',
  'bf-ecb',
  'bf-ofb',
  'blowfish',
  'camellia-128-cbc',
  'camellia-128-cfb',
  'camellia-128-cfb1',
  'camellia-128-cfb8',
  'camellia-128-ecb',
  'camellia-128-ofb',
  'camellia-192-cbc',
  'camellia-192-cfb',
  'camellia-192-cfb1',
  'camellia-192-cfb8',
  'camellia-192-ecb',
  'camellia-192-ofb',
  'camellia-256-cbc',
  'camellia-256-cfb',
  'camellia-256-cfb1',
  'camellia-256-cfb8',
  'camellia-256-ecb',
  'camellia-256-ofb',
  'camellia128',
  'camellia192',
  'camellia256',
  'cast',
  'cast-cbc',
  'cast5-cbc',
  'cast5-cfb',
  'cast5-ecb',
  'cast5-ofb',
  'des',
  'des-cbc',
  'des-cfb',
  'des-cfb1',
  'des-cfb8',
  'des-ecb',
  'des-ede',
  'des-ede-cbc',
  'des-ede-cfb',
  'des-ede-ofb',
  'des-ede3',
  'des-ede3-cbc',
  'des-ede3-cfb',
  'des-ede3-cfb1',
  'des-ede3-cfb8',
  'des-ede3-ofb',
  'des-ofb',
  'des3',
  'desx',
  'desx-cbc',
  'id-aes128-GCM',
  'id-aes192-GCM',
  'id-aes256-GCM',
  'idea',
  'idea-cbc',
  'idea-cfb',
  'idea-ecb',
  'idea-ofb',
  'rc2',
  'rc2-40-cbc',
  'rc2-64-cbc',
  'rc2-cbc',
  'rc2-cfb',
  'rc2-ecb',
  'rc2-ofb',
  'rc4',
  'rc4-40',
  'rc4-hmac-md5',
  'seed',
  'seed-cbc',
  'seed-cfb',
  'seed-ecb',
  'seed-ofb' ]
```

And the following `hashes`:

```
[ 'DSA',
  'DSA-SHA',
  'DSA-SHA1',
  'DSA-SHA1-old',
  'RSA-MD4',
  'RSA-MD5',
  'RSA-MDC2',
  'RSA-RIPEMD160',
  'RSA-SHA',
  'RSA-SHA1',
  'RSA-SHA1-2',
  'RSA-SHA224',
  'RSA-SHA256',
  'RSA-SHA384',
  'RSA-SHA512',
  'dsaEncryption',
  'dsaWithSHA',
  'dsaWithSHA1',
  'dss1',
  'ecdsa-with-SHA1',
  'md4',
  'md4WithRSAEncryption',
  'md5',
  'md5WithRSAEncryption',
  'mdc2',
  'mdc2WithRSA',
  'ripemd',
  'ripemd160',
  'ripemd160WithRSA',
  'rmd160',
  'sha',
  'sha1',
  'sha1WithRSAEncryption',
  'sha224',
  'sha224WithRSAEncryption',
  'sha256',
  'sha256WithRSAEncryption',
  'sha384',
  'sha384WithRSAEncryption',
  'sha512',
  'sha512WithRSAEncryption',
  'shaWithRSAEncryption',
  'ssl2-md5',
  'ssl3-md5',
  'ssl3-sha1',
  'whirlpool' ]
```

Here's my settings:

- `openssl version` is `OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015`
- `node --version` is `v0.12.4`

Comment: @ThomasRegii, thanks, this was more nodejs specific answer.

Comment: You might want to read about encryption algorithms here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554526/comparison-of-des-triple-des-aes-blowfish-encryption-for-data

Comment: @ThomasRegii , old thread I know. Do you know what determines the list of ciphers? Is it the nodejs version, or the computer it’s running on?

Answer (score 5):

```
CAST-cbc
aes-128-cbc

aes-128-cbc-hmac-sha1

aes-128-cfb

aes-128-cfb1

aes-128-cfb8

aes-128-ctr

aes-128-ecb

aes-128-gcm

aes-128-ofb

aes-128-xts

aes-192-cbc

aes-192-cfb

aes-192-cfb1

aes-192-cfb8

aes-192-ctr

aes-192-ecb

aes-192-gcm

aes-192-ofb

aes-256-cbc

aes-256-cbc-hmac-sha1

aes-256-cfb

aes-256-cfb1

aes-256-cfb8

aes-256-ctr

aes-256-ecb

aes-256-gcm

aes-256-ofb

aes-256-xts

aes128

aes192

aes256

bf

bf-cbc

bf-cfb

bf-ecb

bf-ofb

blowfish

camellia-128-cbc

camellia-128-cfb

camellia-128-cfb1

camellia-128-cfb8

camellia-128-ecb

camellia-128-ofb

camellia-192-cbc

camellia-192-cfb

camellia-192-cfb1

camellia-192-cfb8

camellia-192-ecb

camellia-192-ofb

camellia-256-cbc

camellia-256-cfb

camellia-256-cfb1

camellia-256-cfb8

camellia-256-ecb

camellia-256-ofb

camellia128

camellia192

camellia256

cast

cast-cbc

cast5-cbc

cast5-cfb

cast5-ecb

cast5-ofb

des

des-cbc

des-cfb

des-cfb1

des-cfb8

des-ecb

des-ede

des-ede-cbc

des-ede-cfb

des-ede-ofb

des-ede3

des-ede3-cbc

des-ede3-cfb

des-ede3-cfb1

des-ede3-cfb8

des-ede3-ofb

des-ofb

des3

desx

desx-cbc

id-aes128-GCM

id-aes192-GCM

id-aes256-GCM

idea

idea-cbc

idea-cfb

idea-ecb

idea-ofb

rc2

rc2-40-cbc

rc2-64-cbc

rc2-cbc

rc2-cfb

rc2-ecb

rc2-ofb

rc4

rc4-40

rc4-hmac-md5

seed

seed-cbc

seed-cfb

seed-ecb

seed-ofb
```

Answer (score 4):

The openssl docs have a page listing all valid cipher strings:
http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html#CIPHER_STRINGS

Answer (score 3):

[SHA-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-256) is not a cipher, it is a [hash algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). That is probably why you didn't find it in a list of ciphers.
The same goes for MD5 and all the various SHA algorithms.

Indeed, a hash algorithm is exactly what you need for [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC).  If you want to construct a MAC based on a block cipher, you'll need to use some other construction, such as [OMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-key_MAC)/[CMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMAC), [PMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMAC_%28cryptography%29) or [CBC-MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC).

Comment: Thanks for this, I had no clue.

Answer (score 1):

I checked all of the [cipher strings](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html#CIPHER_STRINGS) and everything in my [gist](https://gist.github.com/4459803) and these are the only algo's that work with cipher to create a HMAC.

```
MD5
SHA
SHA1
SHA256
SHA384
```

Comment: Most of the time it is better to wait a bit (a day or two) for others to post answers, especially because your answer is plain wrong :) Best to delete it I suppose, before it gets modded into oblivion.

Comment: @owlstead Name another that can be used to create a hmac. Because if you can't I'm right. I've looped every string provided on this page, all produce errors except the above strings.

Comment: The trouble was more in the name "cipher" (note spelling), for creating a HMAC you need a hash function, and as long as this list reflects the hash functions in openssl, it is correct (it is likely that support for SHA-224, SHA-512/256 and/or SHA-3 will be added in later releases).