# Node.js crypto How to know Key and IV length for each algorithm

Tags: node.js, cryptography, cryptojs

I'm building a desktop application intended to encrypt and decrypt file for users. I would like to let them choose the algorithm.

`crypto.getCiphers()` will return a list of supported algrithoms, but is there a way to know each algrithoms' Key and IV length? For example, `aes256` will be 32 and 16 repectively.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168703/crypto-algorithm-list

Comment: @schoche Thanks, but I still don't know the length of key and IV for each supported algorithm

Comment: are you looking for a specific one? in TLS 1.3 there is only 5 cipher suite available?