# How to use Diffie-Hellman with 2048 bits to create a cipher?

Tags: node.js, encryption, diffie-hellman

I'm trying to find an algorithm within the [list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32618629/2530438) that accommodates 2048 bit length with using `crypto.createDiffieHellman(2048)`. In other words,
I have Alice and Bob using their corresponding secret keys to encrypt/decrypt messages to each other.

```js
const crypto = require('crypto'),
      assert = require('assert'),
      algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc',
      IV_LENGTH = 16,
      DH_LENGTH = 2048;

const alice = crypto.createDiffieHellman(DH_LENGTH);
const aliceKey = alice.generateKeys();

const bob = crypto.createDiffieHellman(alice.getPrime(), alice.getGenerator());
const bobKey = bob.generateKeys();

const aliceSecret = alice.computeSecret(bobKey);
const bobSecret = bob.computeSecret(aliceKey); // should be same as aliceSecret

const password = aliceSecret;
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(IV_LENGTH).toString('hex').slice(0, IV_LENGTH);

function encrypt(text){
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, password, iv)
  const crypted = `${cipher.update(text,'utf8','hex')}${cipher.final('hex')}`
  return crypted;
}


function decrypt(text){
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, password, iv)
  const dec = `${decipher.update(text,'hex','utf8')}${decipher.final('utf8')}`
  return dec;
}

const msg =  encrypt('Test');

const decryptedMsg = decrypt(msg)

console.log(msg, decryptedMsg);
```

This throws an error `Invalid key length`. One way to fix this is to do `DH_LENGTH = 256`. However, this is not a good idea with recommended minimum length being 2048 bits. Now, I can create a key with 2048 and do a slice on a length of 256 but how is this any different from doing a 256 bit DH. Basically the attacker having to guess the first/last 256 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you should stick to the recommended size for DHKE. A common way is using a key derivation function on the output of the Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange.

HKDF is fine for you. HKDF follows the "extract-then-expand" paradigm and, normally, the `expand` would be enough if you find and implementation that gives access to those functions. The below is from [futoin-hkdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/futoin-hkdf);

```
const hkdf = require('futoin-hkdf');

// Parameter overview
//-------------------
// initial keying material
const ikm = 'string-or-buffer';
// required output length in bytes
const length = 32;
// can be empty string or false equivalent
const salt = 'strongly-encouraged';
// optional parameter
const info = 'optional-context';
// HMAC hashing algorithm to use
const hash = 'SHA-256';

// Generic derivation
//-------------------
hkdf(ikm, length, {salt, info, hash}); // Buffer(length) - derived key
```

IKM is your derived key, and please don't call it passwords. It is more than that. Naming like `sharedKey` or `exchangedKey` is better.

The optional context can be used for domain separation so that you can derive different keys for different applications. See the datils here; [Multiple AES Key Derivation from a master key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76588/18298)

And, for forward secrecy, don't forget to erase the key after use.

> - Why should we process the result of the Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange?

The security of Diffie-Hellman key exchange is based on the Decisional Diffie-Hellman assumption. This assumption says that the exchanged key is a group element that is computationally indistinguishable from a random/uniformly distributed element in the group.

One must note that the result is not uniformly distributed element, i.e. each bit has 1/2 probability for being 0 or 1. The MSB may not be uniformly distributed.

The recommended way to extract the extropy is by using a hash or better to be processed by a Key Derivation Function. HKDF would be fine here.

Comment: If I get the gist of this - which actually sounds like I should've thought of - is to take the sharedKey/secret (which is 512 length in hex) and hash it to generate a 32 length key (e.g: md5). I know md5 is terrible lol but want to make sure I get the gist of it.

Comment: @Bwaxxlo updated. Hash is fine. even MD5 is fine. However, keep using good hash functions. If you consider the speed, you might see blake2.

Comment: > And, for forward secrecy, don't forget to erase the key after use.


Could you expand on this part? To me this is a toy app to understand using DH but it'd be great to know why having a shared key for encrypting things isn't future proof.

Comment: Ephemeral Diffie-Hellman provides the [Forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy). This implicitly defines that both sides delete the exchanged keys, otherwise, later an attack can access these keys.