# Time comparision of various Encryption algorithms in Android

Tags: android, performance, encryption, aes

I am developing an android app that encrypts/decrypts any file. It is for my university project.

I am currently using AES with CBC and PKCS#7 [AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding]. My app works good, but I am worried about the time it takes to Encrypt and Decrypt a file.

I was wondering if there is some resource that compares the time taken to Encrypt and Decrypt a sample file of any size using any android hardware.

Also, does the time taken depends only on the size of the file, or also the type of file? This post I read indicated some of those [Comparison of DES, Triple DES, AES, blowfish encryption for data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554526/comparison-of-des-triple-des-aes-blowfish-encryption-for-data)

I have also read that there is not much choice when we work in Android except for AES.

I want to include a comparative study of at least 3 algorithms and justify my usage of AES over others.

Besides this, I have discovered AES acceleration is possible with newer Intel Core family processors called AES-NI (http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-advanced-encryption-standard-instructions-aes-ni/), but as far as I understood they are only available to Intel processors, not for Android processors (which do not use Intel). Please correct me on this if I am wrong.